# Retrieve Xml attribute value using XElement and modified and send back c#

Tags: c#

I have below mention input. I found this xml input as string and fetch datetime field as desired and change there datetime to utcdatetime and also want to change in diffrent UTC format.After change modify this xml and send back for peocess. using c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

```
        //Find a specific Node according to the name

        var specific = (from e in doc.Descendants("User")
                        where e.Attribute("Name").Value == "EmpNo"
                        select e).First();

        //Change the name property
        specific.Attribute("Name").Value = "New Name Property";
        specific.Attribute("Value").Value = "New Value Property";

        //Add a new element
        specific.SetAttributeValue("EmpId", "1");
```